# measure of multivariate skewness

Tags: multivariate-analysis, descriptive-statistics, skewness

I am looking for a generalization of [Pearson's](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PearsonsSkewnessCoefficients.html) or the Yule-Kendall's skewness measures, from univariate to multivariate data.

If not a proper generalization, any other measure sensitive to the breaking of central (a.k.a. antipodal) symmetry will serve nicely.